# Moving Files in a Folder

Tags: shell-script

I am taking the user input and trying to move a specific file in a folder which is specified by user (The folder does not exist beforehand). I have written a script for this but its not working.

```
read month
mv file210.txt /Users/PrashastKumar/Documents/latestFiles/$month/
```

After executing this i am getting error as below

```
mv: rename file210.txt to /Users/PrashastKumar/Documents/latestFiles/Dec/: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the folder does not exist, you will have to create it:

```
#!/bin/sh

read month

folder="/Users/PrashastKumar/Documents/latestFiles/$month"

mkdir -p "$folder"

mv file210.txt "$folder"
```

The script will create the folder using `mkdir -p` which will not fail if the folder is already existing and will create any intermediate folders as needed.

Then the file is moved.

---

Expanded the script with a confirmation before creating a new folder:

```
#!/bin/sh

read month

folder="/Users/PrashastKumar/Documents/latestFiles/$month"

if [ ! -d "$folder" ]; then
    printf 'Folder "%s" does not exist. Create it [y/n]: ' "$folder" >&2
    read
    case "$REPLY" in 
        [yY]*)  mkdir -p "$folder" ;;
        *) exit 1
    esac
fi

mv file210.txt "$folder"
```